# Timestamp to: Days - Hours - Minutes

Tags: php

Can someone please tell me how can I convert a specific timestamp to days - hours - minutes in PHP?

For example I'd like to get something like this: (20 days 13 hours 35 minutes) from a random timestamp like this: 534222234

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by random? What kind of a timestamp is it? is it a seconds time stamp? unix epoch timestamp?

Comment: "20 days 13 hours 35 minutes" from what starting point?

Comment: Its a timestmp of 2 substracted timestamp value. Like I substract 2012/05/10 from today and I get a timestamp value. That is what I want the code to cont into days, hours, minutes.

Answer (score 10):

```
function time2string($time) {
    $d = floor($time/86400);
    $_d = ($d < 10 ? '0' : '').$d;

    $h = floor(($time-$d*86400)/3600);
    $_h = ($h < 10 ? '0' : '').$h;

    $m = floor(($time-($d*86400+$h*3600))/60);
    $_m = ($m < 10 ? '0' : '').$m;

    $s = $time-($d*86400+$h*3600+$m*60);
    $_s = ($s < 10 ? '0' : '').$s;

    $time_str = $_d.':'.$_h.':'.$_m.':'.$_s;

    return $time_str;
}
```

example of using:

```
echo time2string(86500); // 01:00:01:40  dd:hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of what im doing for min, seconds

```
function convertToMinSec($time) {
    $min = intval(($time / 60) % 60);
    $minSec = $min.'m ';

    $sec = intval($time % 60);
    $sec = str_pad($sec, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $minSec .= $sec.'s';

    return $minSec;
}
```

What this is doing is for minutes it gets the time(in seconds) divides by 60 and gets the mod of 60.  This will get the number of minutes.

Then I do basically the same to get the seconds (mod is remainder) and then I pad the left if it is under 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as follow

```
$now = date_create("now");
$other_date = date_create("2012/05/10");
$interval = date_diff($now, $other_date);
$interval->format("d h i");
```

Comment: +1 for use of the native PHP API.  Although it should be mentioned that this is only available in PHP versions >= 5.3

Comment: This is great.  However I think the question is how to convert seconds to be (d h i)  This will work but it would require some extra work in changing how the user gets the seconds

Comment: Yes my qzestion is how to convert the seconds to days, hours, minutes.

Comment: So perhaps you should look into bretterer's answer.
There are 84600 seconds in a day (24 * 60 * 60), divide it by the interval and you get the days, the remainder is the amount of hours and seconds left, divide it again by 3600 (60 * 60) seconds in an hour to get the amount of hours left and the remainder is the amount of seconds left.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a timestamp using the date-function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

My code has support for both years and weeks

```
function array2readable($array, $separator, $last_separator) {                              
    $result = preg_replace(strrev("/$separator/"),strrev($last_separator),strrev(implode($separator, $array)), 1);
    return strrev($result);
}

function unixTime2text($time) {
    $value['y'] = floor($time/31536000);
    $value['w'] = floor(($time-($value['y']*31536000))/604800);
    $value['d'] = floor(($time-($value['y']*31536000+$value['w']*604800))/86400);
    $value['h'] = floor(($time-($value['y']*31536000+$value['w']*604800+$value['d']*86400))/3600);
    $value['m'] = floor(($time-($value['y']*31536000+$value['w']*604800+$value['d']*86400+$value['h']*3600))/60);
    $value['s'] = $time-($value['y']*31536000+$value['w']*604800+$value['d']*86400+$value['h']*3600+$value['m']*60);

    $unit['y'] = 'year' . ($value['y'] > 1 ? 's' : '');
    $unit['w'] = 'week' . ($value['w'] > 1 ? 's' : '');
    $unit['d'] = 'day' . ($value['d'] > 1 ? 's' : '');
    $unit['h'] = 'hour' . ($value['h'] > 1 ? 's' : '');
    $unit['m'] = 'minute' . ($value['m'] > 1 ? 's' : '');
    $unit['s'] = 'second' . ($value['s'] > 1 ? 's' : '');

    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        if (!empty($val)) {
            $not_null_values[] .= $val . ' ' . $unit[$key];
        }
    }

    return array2readable($not_null_values, ', ', ' and ');
}
```

## Example 1

```
echo unixTime2text(1776900); # 20 days 13 hours 35 minutes
```

## Example 2

```
echo unixTime2text(534222234); # 16 years, 49 weeks, 3 hours, 3 minutes and 54 seconds
```